# jplayer not working in ie8 but is fine in other browsers

Tags: jquery, jsp, audio, jplayer

my jplayer isn't working in ie 8. i tried moving the swfpath to root site, as that seems like some people's solution. but it's still not working.

Could anyone tell which part is wrong?

The demo player seems to work fine on ie8

site is :
mactelwebdesign.com.au

frustraaateddd. 
it works fine in chrome and firefox

Comment: To anyone reading this in the post-2.1-era: 2.2 seems to have addressed this issue and playback on IE8 (and IE7) works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Version 2.1 of jPlayer.swf (8.2Kb) doesn't work in IE. You should use version 2.0.0 and set `swfPath` to the full address. Setting `swfPath` to the link below solves the problem:

```
swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/2.0.0/js"
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason IE needs play twice. So I used:

```
$("#JPL").jPlayer("play",0); //to set track to beginning and start playing
$("#JPL").jPlayer("play"); //another line to fix IE stuck issue
```

Answer (score 0):

this player doesn't work in Safari, either.. try changing your constructor to this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"http://mactel.com.au/webdesign/music.mp3",
            oga:"http://mactel.com.au/webdesign/music.ogg"

        }).jPlayer("play");
    },
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

Comment: i did, and now the time-length number changes from 0.00 until 7.11 but i still can't play it on explorer. Have a look

Comment: But if i click into the middle of the song and click play, it works. seems like the autoPlay not working now?

Answer (score 0):

I update this subject because I found an issue to this problem.

I don't know why but you have to write an absolute link for the m4v link.

```
  $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
   m4v: "video.m4v",
   ogv: "video.ogv",
   webm: "video.webm",
   mp4: "video.mp4"
   }).jPlayer("play");
```

This code is fine on all browsers except IE8, but if you change :

-> m4v: "video.m4v",

by

-> m4v: "http://absoluteurl.com/folder/video.m4v",

It works ! Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Just to add this though quite late in the day. I just had a very similar problem.

I hosted the jplayer.swf locally, change solution to "flash,html", set OggSupport and nativeSupport to false, and last added wmode set to window, I then only load jplayer if the browser is IE8, otherwise I rely on native browser support for the audio tag.

Code below for the record.

```
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                    mp3: audioFile
                });
            },
            swfPath: theme_dir+"/js",
            supplied: "mp3",
            solution: "flash, html",
            oggSupport: false,
            nativeSupport: false,
            wmode: "window"
        });
```